# redirect non-www to www with https excluding cdn and other sub domains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Right now I have this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# remove the .html extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.html\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ $1 [R=301]

# remove index and reference the directory
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]

# remove trailing slash if not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

# forward request to html file, **but don't redirect (bot friendly)**
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.html [L]

#First rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use the correct one (here www.)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#Now, rewrite to HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Its working perfectly fine, however it's redirecting our cdn images from cdn.domain.com/img.jpg to www.domain.com/img.jpg how can I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent this by prefixing your rules with a condition testing for `cdn.` and no substitution

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cdn\.
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

This rule leaves the URL as it is `-`

> **- (dash)**
>
> A dash indicates that no substitution should be performed
>   (the existing path is passed through untouched). This is used
>   when a flag (see below) needs to be applied without changing
>   the path.

and stops further rewriting [`L|last`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l)

> The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set.

Comment: It's still redirecting cdn.domain.com/url/img.jpg to www.domain.com/url/img.jpg

Comment: Where would I add the code, can you check my refreshed code at the OP.

Comment: When you put this rule at the beginning, then all requests for `cdn.domain.com` will not be rewritten.

Comment: I added your code right under RewriteBase / but it still seems to be redirecting cdn.domain.com/img to www.domain.com/img